# Qt designer: how to do minor animation?

Tags: qt-designer

I don't have `Qt Creator`. I'm looking for a solution within `Qt Designer` to add a `button` to the form so that if the user `presses` it, an image `appears/disappears`, or an image moves from one position to another. 
Thanks

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think you need to do that in C++. Just write slots that do what you want, then connect appropriate signals as usual.

Comment: so where should this code be written? how is the link to the .ui file?

Comment: If you want C++ code, you need a full Qt project. Sounds like you should start with Qt basics. Using Qt Creator would also be a great help, because in Qt Creator's version of Designer you have "Go to slot..." operation, which will generate a C++ slot (based on your button object name, so that it will be automatically connected by the code generated from your .ui XML).